# Dynamically set Receive Pipeline- Biztalk 2016

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-2016

What I'm trying to do is set up a decoupled/flexible framework/strategy for all applications I develop in the future, that includes as much 're-use' as possible. Preferably what I'd love to have in the end is a single orchestration that I can 'plug-in' to any other orchestration which will take a message and send to a send adapter and return the response to the calling orchestration (having converted the received response to XML dynamically based on the constructed message to the adapter). This would require being able to set the receive pipeline on the message in the orchestration.

Am I on the right track here? I can't find much on what the best practice is in regards to artifact re-use in BizTalk.

Comment: Sounds a bit overkill to me to have an Orchestration just for calling a send port.  Have you tried just having direct bound orchestrations (publishing message to the message box) and having filters on the send ports to subscribe to the messages?  Are even message only solutions (no Orchestrations at all)?

Comment: This doesn't fulfill my requirement of using single send adapter for many different endpoints but I am looking into direct bound ports since this still seems to be an efficient way to route messages. I cant find a good sample of direct bound ports though. There is a reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-use-messagebox-direct-bound-ports) to a sample called 'Direct Binding to the MessageBox Database in Orchestrations' but the link is broken.

Comment: For dynamically doing things such as transforms or context properties in a Pipeline we use the BRE Pipeline framework https://github.com/mbrimble/brepipelineframework    However that is not yet compatible with BizTalk 2016, although it is being worked on.  The link you have works, try refreshing it, sometimes the Microsoft site glitches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such comes up from time to time and I can tell you, it just never works out.  You will spend a lot of time building essentially a framework, only to never actually use it beyond a handful of situations.

Meaning, no one tries this anymore because it was never actually useful.  You might want to look at the ESB Toolkit, but even that almost always makes things more complicated than needed.

If you describe some of your scenarios, we can give the best advice.

Comment: Ok, well thanks for the response. I'll take this as the answer. I think I'll have to just make the most use of direct bound logical ports as I can and have to just accept having more physical ports than I'd like.